# What is the maximum reference count in std::shared_ptr? What happens if you try to exceed it?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, reference-counting

If we assume that `std::shared_ptr` stores a reference count (which I realize the standard does not require, but I am unaware of any implementations that don't), that reference count has a limited number of bits, and that means there is a maximum number of references that are supported.  That leads to two questions:

- What is this maximum value?
- What happens if you try to exceed it (e.g., by copying a std::shared_ptr that refers to an object with the maximum reference count)?  Note that `std::shared_ptr`'s copy constructor is declared `noexcept`.

Does the standard shed any light on either of these questions?  How about common implementations, e.g., gcc, MSVC, Boost?

Comment: Answer to 2nd question should be "undefined behavior".

Comment: Possible answer to first: Implementation specific. Probably `size_t` or similar, which will be 32 or 64 bits depending on platform.

Comment: In practical terms, you will never hit a limit; you will run out of memory long before you overflow a ref counter. Are you actually facing this problem?

Comment: *My* implementation doesn't use a reference count.

Comment: How do you do implement it w/o a reference count?

Comment: @Nevin - check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725142/how-does-a-reference-counting-smart-pointers-reference-counting-work/725197#725197

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, current popular implementations use 32 bit, even on x86-64, cf. my answer

Comment: @tenfour - if the counter is just 32 bit, you have small objects and a system in the order of - say - 128 GiB RAM than a counter isn't that unrealistic, anymore - cf. my answer

Comment: Both GCC and Clang on my x86-64 Linux system uses 64 bits for `size_t`. Both are pretty popular implementations, on a pretty popular system.

Comment: @Nevin You could use a linked list of owners, but it isn't very easy to make thread safe w/o global locks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can get some information from the `shared_ptr::use_count()` function. §20.7.2.2.5 says:

```
long use_count() const noexcept;
```

> Returns: the number of `shared_ptr` objects, `*this` included, that share
>   ownership with `*this`, or `0` when `*this` is empty.
>
> [Note: `use_count()` is not necessarily efficient.—end note ]

At first sight the `long` return type seems to answer the first question. However the note seems to imply that `shared_ptr` is free to use any type of reference counting it wants to, including things like a list of references. If this were the case then theoretically there would be no maximum reference count (although there would certainly be a *practical* limit).

There is no other reference to limits on the number of references to the same object that I could find.

It's interesting to note that `use_count` is documented to both not throw and (obviously) to report the count correctly; unless the implementation does use a `long` member for the count I don't see how both of these can be theoretically guaranteed at all times.

Comment: Nice analysis. Can you find any hints about the underlying reference counting done on the shared state held between promises and futures?

Comment: Concerning your last statement, they can't, and the standard has a couple of passages which let the implementation off the hook.  In particular, exceeding resource limits is undefined behavior, and the results of converting a different integral type to a `long` are implementation defined if the value doesn't fit.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 does indeed use a long for _Uses and _Weaks in their _Ref_count_base class used by shared_ptr.

Comment: I wonder why it is long and not unsigned long.  It doesn't seem possible at first glance to have a negative number of references.

Comment: @JamesKanza "he results of converting a different integral type to a long are implementation defined if the value doesn't fit." - that is not relevant here, because the result is still necessarily incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what the standard suggests, but look at it practically:

The *reference count* is most likely some sort of `std::size_t` variable. This variable can hold values up to `-1+2^32` in 32-Bit environments and up to `-1+2^64` in 64-Bit environments.

Now Image what would have to happen for this variable to reach this value: you would need 2^32 or 2^64 `shared_ptr` instances. That's a lot. In fact, that's so many that all memory would be exhausted long before you reach this number, since a one `shared_ptr` is about 8/16 bytes large.

Therefor, you are very unlikely to be able to reach the limit of the reference count if the size of the refcount variable is large enough.

Comment: @tenfour That's right, and here is why: I do not know of an implementation that has a refcount smaller than std::size(). You're right, that doesn't mean it's prohibited by the standard, but in practical terms I think it answers the question.

Comment: If you replace "cannot" with "are extremely unlikely to be able to", then I think everyone would be happy.

Comment: @fat-lobyte This is all valid for machines with flat addressing, but I've worked on segmented machines with 48 bit addresses and 23 bit `size_t`.  (The processor in question was an 80386.  Hardly an exotic.)  If the machine has flat addressing, then you can safely say "cannot".  If it doesn't, I'm not even sure you can say "extremely unlikely".

Answer (score 7):

The standard doesn't say; as you say, it doesn't even require reference
counting.  On the other hand, there is (or was) a statement in the
standard (or at least in the C standard) that exceeding implementation
limits is undefined behavior.  So that's almost certainly the official
answer.

In practice, I would expect most implementations to maintain the count
as a `size_t` or a `ptrdiff_t`.  On machines with flat addressing, this
pretty much means that you cannot create enough references to cause an
overflow.  (On such machines, a single object could occupy all of the
memory, and `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` have the same size as a pointer. 
Since every reference counted pointer has a distinct address, there can
never be more than would fit in a pointer.)  On machines with segmented
architectures, however, overflow is quite conceivable.

As Jon points out, the standard also requires
`std::shared_ptr::use_count()` to return a `long`.  I'm not sure what
the rationale is here: either `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` would make more
sense here.  But if the implementation uses a different type for the
reference count, presumably, the rules for conversion to `long` would
apply: "the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the
destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is
implementation-defined."  (The C standard makes this somewhat clearer:
the "implementation-defined value" can be a signal.)

Comment: "I'm not sure what the rationale is here" - to sneak one past Microsoft, since they're the only people who want `long` to be narrower than `size_t`?

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't know if there was a rationale, at least in the C++ committee.  I think that they just took over what Boost had done (and I have no idea what the rational was in Boost).

Answer (score 2):

You can find out what will happen by instantiating shared pointers using placement new and never deleting them. You can then hit the 32-bit limit easily.

Answer (score 1):

The C++11 standard specifies `long` as the return type of the `use_count()` observer function, but doesn't explicitly specify if an implementation must support up to `2^(sizeof(long)*8-1)-1` shared ownerships.

It also doesn't specify what happens when the reference counter overflows.

The `boost::shared_ptr` implementation (e.g. 1.58 on Fedora 23, x86-64) internally uses 32 Bit counter and doesn't check for overflows.

That means:

1. the maximum reference count is `2^31-1`.
2. if you have an overflow and release ownership you may end up with some use-after-free issues

Since boost uses different low-level specializations for different platforms you can verify the details via setting a breakpoint in `*add_ref_lock` - on Fedora 23/x86-64 you'll stop here:

```
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp
[..]
int use_count_;        // #shared
int weak_count_;       // #weak + (#shared != 0)
[..]
bool add_ref_lock() // true on success
{
    return atomic_conditional_increment( &use_count_ ) != 0;
}
```

See also:

- [Integer overflow in use counter of shared pointers - Boost Ticket 12335](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12335)
- [Twice the Bits, Twice the Trouble: Vulnerabilities Induced by Migrating to 64-Bit Platforms](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/Medien-DB/sec/pubs/2016-ccs.pdf)

The GNU STL (libstdc++) shared_pointer implementation is based on Boost 1.32 one and also has this issue (on Fedora 23/x86-64) - there the `_Atomic_word` type is used for reference counting. It is also 'only' 32 bit and isn't checked for overflow.

In contrast, the LLVM libc++ `shared_ptr` implementation uses a `long` as reference counter, i.e. on LP64 platforms like x86-64 you can share an object between up to `2^63-1` owners.